# Block a user who logs in from two different locations at the same time

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do I block a user who logs in from two different locations at the same time?
Is there any module available?

Answer (score 1):

The session limit module has a beta version for Drupal 7 - http://drupal.org/project/session_limit.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [session limit](http://drupal.org/project/session_limit) to 1 and Bob's your uncle...